# Jquery - .one does not unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

i have the following situation:
i have an animated graph, at the end of the animation i want to add a click handler to a "dead" link, which then hides the actual slide and shows the next. i bind it with .one, cause i dont want to fire it again after loading.
so it works, it shows the next slide, but the event is not unbinding.
even if i unbind it manually it fires the event.

can someone give me a clue?
thx
jesta

```
$("li#slide3").off().on("click", $(this), function() {
$("#slide3 .device").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, function() {
    $("#slide3 .device").animate({opacity:0}, 1000, function() {
        console.log($("li#slide3 img.graph_adds").data("height"));
        $("li#slide3 img.graph_adds").animate({height:$("li#slide3 img.graph_adds").data("height")}, 1500, function() {
            $("#book_container").one("click", "a#book", function(ev) {  
                ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if (!animBook) {    initialiseAnimatedImages(); }
                $("li.active_slide").fadeOut(500, function() {

                    $("li#slide4").addClass("active_slide").fadeIn(1000);
                    resetSlides();
                }).removeClass("active_slide");

            });
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: must...avoid... meme joke... d'oh https://imgflip.com/i/j3hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, i think i found the solution. the animation was the problem. cause there were multiple devices and graphs with my code-structure each device was firing the function code, so device1 fired, then the two graphs fired two time, then device2 fired them again and so on.

with the .promise().done() structure all is just fired once, the animation works and all events are just fired once. now it should work too that i bind the elements in the .on()-statements, cause now they should bind only once then...but...nevah change a running system ^^

```
$("li#slide3").on("click", $("div.slide3"), function(ev) {
$("#slide3 .device").animate({opacity:1}, 1000).promise().done(function() {
    $("#slide3 .device").animate({opacity:0}, 1000).promise().done(function() {
        console.log("slide3-height: "+$("li#slide3 img.graph_adds3").data("height"));
        $("li#slide3 img.graph_adds3").animate({height:$("li#slide3 img.graph_adds3").data("height")}, 1500).promise().done(function() {
            console.log("slide3 click");
            if(!$("a#book").hasClass("slide_4") ) {
            $("a#book").addClass("slide_3"); }
        });
    });
}).promise().done(function() { console.log("div.slide3 anim don") });
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Here is JQuery command that removes all bindings from the element:

```
$("#book_container").unbind();  //to flush previously bound actions
```

Comment: have tried unbinding, off and so on...strange is the fact, that sometimes it works...othertimes it takes 2 clicks to get .one to work, sometimes three...